# Why isnt AutoIt performing a click?

Tags: autoit

My Code in AutoIt doesn't click, it opens up the file, but doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

Could it be because there's another Window in between asking for my Administrator Password?

```
Run("Setup.exe")
WinWait("Mozilla Firefox-Installation", "Willkommen beim ")
WinActivate("Mozilla Firefox-Installation", "Willkommen beim ")
ControlClick("Mozilla Firefox-Installation", "Willkommen beim ", "Abbrechen", "left")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma compile(ExecLevel, requireAdministrator)
#RequireAdmin

Run("Setup.exe")
WinWait("Mozilla Firefox-Installation", "Willkommen beim ")
WinActivate("Mozilla Firefox-Installation", "Willkommen beim ")
ControlClick("Mozilla Firefox-Installation", "Willkommen beim ", "Abbrechen")
```

The [`#pragma compile`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/directives/pragma-compile.htm) directive to set `ExecLevel`
to `requireAdministrator` allows the AutoIt script compiled
to executable, in the manifest, to run as Administrator.

The [`#RequireAdmin`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/RequireAdmin.htm) directive allows the executed
au3 file to run as Administrator.

The [`ControlClick`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm) may not be allowed happen if the AutoIt process
is running as not an Administrator and the process to be
automated is running as Administrator.

The optional parameter of `left` can be omitted form the
`ControlClick` function call as it is already the default.

Note that Firefox supports a `-ms` silent install argument
so GUI automation can be avoided.